# Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled

Tags: mysql, database, easyphp

Im trying to start MySQL using easyPHP: the response is an alert window to a log file. The main error is *<-- Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled -->*.

Through research online I found that the solution is to add the federated option to the `my.ini` file. I did this, but it is still not working.

Here is an extract from the log file for more information:

```
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 1b4c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 12 MB
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-05-03 14:12:57 3776 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 0
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: cadcd135-b3ea-11e2-92bc-e0db55e1304d.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-05-03 14:12:58 3776 [Note] C:\PROGRA~1\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.11-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-05-03 14:15:59 3776 [Note] C:\PROGRA~1\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
```

Comment: That's not an error - it's being reported as a notice. Do you need the federated engine? What is it that you are trying to fix which led you to looking at the log file?

Comment: What I need is just launch MySQL from EasyPHP. Actually I have every time an alert box "Unexpected end of MySql... See log file ?".

Comment: Look at the last entry in the log - the server was shut down. (did not crash).

Comment: I checked the task manager, the mysqld.exe is not shut down

Answer (score 39):

The message about FEDERATED disabled is not an error. It just meant that the FEDERATED engine its not ON for your mysql server. It's not used by default. If you don't need it, don't care about this message.

> The **FEDERATED** storage engine is available beginning with MySQL 5.0.3. It is a storage engine that accesses data in tables of remote databases rather than in local tables.

More info on federated engine can be found at this link:

- [The FEDERATED Storage Engine - MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: So why does MySQL feel the need to tell you about this?  There are plenty of other features that you may not have enabled and it doesn't tell you about any of those!