# MySQL repeatedly crashing

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL database which keeps crashing.  I'm not a MySQL expert (or even amateur) and don't know what's wrong.  Can you help?  This is from the error log:

```
2017-02-22T08:12:11.693717Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-02-22T08:12:11.693807Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-02-22T08:12:11.856081Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp serv$
2017-02-22T08:12:11.858080Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 3034 ...
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862156Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862178Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862193Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862198Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862437Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-02-22T08:12:11.862551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864011Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864045Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864057Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864064Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864070Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864074Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864079Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864082Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-02-22T08:12:11.864088Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864133Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864144Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-02-22T08:12:11.864369Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965638/mysql-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-the-buffer-pool/32932601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply running out of space.  Increased the server and now running